# PDO Syntax Bugs

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I found a cool AJAX tutorial that has one problem: Its MySQL queries aren't updated to PDO.

So I'm trying to fix three errors: mysql_insert_id(), mysql_num_rows(), mysql_fetch_array(). I Googled fixes for all three, but I apparently botched at least one. I can't tell exactly where the problem is.

This is the original code...

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (id, user_name,score,category_id)VALUES ('NULL','$name',0,'$category')") or die(mysql_error());

$_SESSION['name']= $name;
$_SESSION['id'] = mysql_insert_id();
```

and...

```
$res = mysql_query("select * from questions where category_id='$category' ORDER BY RAND()") or die(mysql_error());

$rows = mysql_num_rows($res);

$i=1;
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($res)){?>
```

And here's my makeover:

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (id, user_name,score,category_id)VALUES ('NULL','$name',0,'$category')");
$stm->execute(array(
));

$_SESSION['name']= $name;
$_SESSION['id'] = lastInsertId;
```

and...

```
$res = $pdo->prepare("select * from questions where category_id='$category' ORDER BY RAND()");
$res->execute(array(
));

$num_rows = $res->fetchColumn();

$i=1;

$row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));{?>
```

Can anyone see my mistake(s)?

Comment: You should add the exact error messages you get.

Comment: Well you have a random `{` at the end. Look like you forgot to add a `while` loop.

Comment: Please find that the line `$_SESSION['id'] = lastInsertId;` should most probably look like `$_SESSION['id'] = $pdo->lastInsertId();` since `lastInsertId` is a method of PDO object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL errors you get are because you are not writing your queries correctly.

Let's first build the SQL string. Notice that the variables have been replaced by a colon (`:`) and an alphanumerical identifier.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (id, user_name, score, category_id) VALUES ('NULL', :name, 0, :category)"
```

Then prepare it:

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
```

Then execute it. You pass it an array of values, keyed on the parameter name:

```
$stm->execute(array(
    ':name' => $name,
    ':category' => $category,
));
```

Finally, you can put the values you used in the session array:

```
$_SESSION['name']= $name;
$_SESSION['id'] = $pdo->lastInsertId;
```

You'll have to do something similar for the second query.

Answer (score 0):

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (id, user_name, score, category_id)VALUES(NULL, :name, 0, :category)");


$params = array(":name" => $_SESSION['name']= $name, ":category" => $_SESSION['id'] = lastInsertId);
$stm->execute($params);
```

This should do the trick for the first PDO query. I'm going to use it as an example to teach you.

PDO prepares the statement. That means that the query is actually build by the database driver and not by PHP. So passing the PHP params in the query isn't the way to go. The params need to be added to the function via the execute statement.

Inside your `SQL` you can refer to these params with `:variable`. Notice the colon `:`. You can only use each variable once! Supply the params as array to the function execute where `:variable` is the array `key` and combined with the `value` you want to send to the database.

Comment: I recommend mentioning the users code at the very bottom. The user forgot to add a while loop and will crash if it's not fixed: `$row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));{?>` to `while( $row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ){?>`.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips. I think all the answers are correct. Note that I didn't post the entire code (which includes a while loop) because I didn't want to overwhelm you with all that code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use parameters:

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (id, user_name,score,category_id) VALUES (NULL,:name ,0,:category)");
$stm->execute(array(
  ':name' => $name,
  ':category' => $category
));
```

LastInsertId is prop of `PDO`

```
$_SESSION['name']= $name;
$_SESSION['id'] = $pdo->lastInsertId;
```

Again use params:

```
$res = $pdo->prepare("select * from questions where category_id=:category ORDER BY RAND()");
$res->execute(array(
   ':category' => $category
));
```

You can use `PDOStatement::rowCount` to get the number of rows:

```
$num_rows = $res->rowCount();
```

And Finally to fetch results:

```
while(false !== ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Or in an html output context:

```
<?php while(false !== ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))): ?>
   <!-- html and php output code here -->
<?php endwhile; ?>
```